# bash script to run multiple C++ codes only after previous code has been finished

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run multiple C++ codes using bash script on a Linux cluster. I am able to do that but as multiple codes run at the same time on the cluster it becomes slow. Therefore, I want to run these simulations using bash script such that, the next code only starts running when the previous one has been completed.

I have been using sleep command for now by specifying number of hours it might run but as I do not know the run time before hand it is very inefficient. The next code has to wait till the sleep time is over.

This how my current bash script looks

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/Rectilinear_box_Loverl_16
make clean
make -f Makefile
echo "L/l = 16 started"
./Rod input_file.xml > log &
sleep 14h
echo "L/l = 16 completed"

cd /home/Rectilinear_box_Loverl_14
make clean
make -f Makefile
echo "\nL/l = 14 started"
./Rod input_file.xml > log &
sleep 14h
echo "L/l = 14 completed"

cd /home/Rectilinear_box_Loverl_12
make clean
make -f Makefile
echo "\nL/l = 12 started"
./Rod input_file.xml > log &
echo "L/l = 12 completed"
```

each code takes different amount of time to finish but I have specified the maximum amount of time to be safe.

Could someone suggest a good way to do it?

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `&`. They make your calculations execute in the background.

```
./Rod input_file.xml > log &
```

Can be:

```
./Rod input_file.xml > log
```

Comment: I want them to run in the background so that they don't stop when the terminal is closed.

Comment: Then you should run the whole script in the background (as in `./your_script.sh &`), rather than each step separately. Also, depending on the signal handling in `Rod` this way of job control may break anyway. Read up on using `screen` for something better.

Comment: Also, you'll want to check out `nohup` for running scripts in the background on configurations where logging out will do a hangup or fail when a background process is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not run your programs in the background, it will not move to the next command until that particular run is complete.

For example, remove your sleep commands and do this:

```
./Rod input_file.xml > log
```

And NOT:

```
./Rod input_file.xml > log &
```

Remove the ampersand indicating it should run.  Also I recommend putting this at the top:
    touch log

And use the `>>` instead of `>` to append to the log.

Comment: Of course the logging recommendation is only relevant if the log isn't removed by `make clean`.  Otherwise you might as well pipe the output to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

You may start a background process (in this example `sleep 5` is the background process) and wait for it. Try this example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Do job #1
sleep 5 &
sleeppid=$!

# Wait for job #1 to finish
echo sleep started: $(date)
wait "$sleeppid"
echo sleep ended: $(date)

# Do job #2
sleep 5 &
sleeppid=$!

# Wait for job #2 to finish
echo sleep started: $(date)
wait "$sleeppid"
echo sleep ended: $(date)
```

Comment: Of course, in this example the OP just wants the next command to execute when the previous command completes.  However, this is a good way to do it if you don't want the script to exit on failure.  There are other ways, though.  Like:   `./someCommand || echo "that command failed" >&2`